# Deploy multiple ARM Templates in parallel with PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, deployment, azure-resource-manager

I created a Resource Manager Project in Visual Studio 2017 and as result got `Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1` that deploys the template to Azure. But I have multiple templates and would like to be able to deploy them in parallel with PowerShell. My current approach iterates over each template and deploys them sequentially what takes a lot of time.

How can I achieve that?

Edit: taking the response from @4c74356b41 into account. I need to execute some more logic as part of the job. Therefore it is not enough just to execute the ResourceGroupDeployment in parallel.

Comment: If you're interested, [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/) can greatly simplify deployments. The day we moved from PowerShell to Terraform was a beautiful day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all get all relevant templates e.g. via

`$armTemplateFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot -Include *.JobTemplate.json -Recurse;`

- Now iterate over each template file and create a job for each one (these jobs are then executed in parallel)

Code:

```
foreach ($armTemplateFile in $armTemplateFiles) {
    $logic = {
        Param(
            [object] 
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $ctx,

            [object] 
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $armTemplateFile,

            [string] 
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            $resourceGroupName
        )

        function Format-ValidationOutput {
            param ($ValidationOutput, [int] $Depth = 0)
            Set-StrictMode -Off
            return @($ValidationOutput | Where-Object { $_ -ne $null } | ForEach-Object { @('  ' * $Depth + ': ' + $_.Message) + @(Format-ValidationOutput @($_.Details) ($Depth + 1)) })
        }

        # Get related parameters file
        $paramTemplateFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $armTemplateFile.FullName.Replace("JobTemplate.json", "JobTemplate.parameters.json")

        # Test Deployment
        $ErrorMessages = Format-ValidationOutput (Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
                                                                                        -TemplateFile $armTemplateFile.FullName `
                                                                                        -TemplateParameterFile $paramTemplateFile.FullName `
                                                                                        -DefaultProfile $ctx)
        if ($ErrorMessages) {
            Write-Host '', 'Validation returned the following errors:', @($ErrorMessages), '', 'Template is invalid.'
        }
        else { # Deploy

            New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name (($armTemplateFile.Name).Split(".")[0] + ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('MMddHHmm')) `
                                                -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
                                                -TemplateFile $armTemplateFile.FullName `
                                                -TemplateParameterFile $paramTemplateFile.FullName `
                                                -Force `
                                                -ErrorVariable ErrorMessages `
                                                -DefaultProfile $ctx
            if ($ErrorMessages) {
                Write-Host '', 'Template deployment returned the following errors:', @(@($ErrorMessages) | ForEach-Object { $_.Exception.Message.TrimEnd("`r`n") })
            }
        }
    }
    Start-Job $logic -ArgumentList (Get-AzureRmContext), $armTemplateFile, $ResourceGroupName
}

While (Get-Job -State "Running")
{
    Start-Sleep 10
    Write-Host "Jobs still running..."
}

Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

Answer (score 1):

Extremely bad solution, a lot of overcomplication.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroup xxx -TemplateFile xxx -AsJob
```

and you need a loop on top of this

Comment: good to know when there is a better way :) I will test if what you proposed works the way I need it. But what I have shown is only part of the total story. I have some more logic in the code that is not relevant to the question and these steps also need to be parallized. Therefore my approach could make sense ;)